# Modify a table from script in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a Google Doc containing one table. I'm trying to write a script that appends a number of empty rows to a table, how can I do that?

I've tried with the following function:

```
function insertRows2() {
  var NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 40;

  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody(),
      searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE),
      element = searchElement.getElement(),
      table = element.asTable();

  Logger.log('num rows: ' + table.getNumRows());

  for (var i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++) {
    table.appendTableRow();
  }

  Logger.log('num rows: ' + table.getNumRows());
}
```

The output is:

```
[14-11-25 15:02:26:275 CET] num rows: 1077
[14-11-25 15:02:26:353 CET] num rows: 1117
```

But I don't see the newly created rows in the document.
If I manually insert a row form the UI, and then re-execute the script I get:

```
[14-11-25 15:04:24:317 CET] num rows: 1118
[14-11-25 15:04:24:400 CET] num rows: 1158
```

So it seems that the code is actually working on the right table, but I don't see the new rows in the document itself.

The log says 1158 rows but the document actually just has ~30 rows

Comment: I _think_ you're appending empty rows, and that _empty_ isn't the same as _blank_. The UI is probably adding _blank_ rows. What happens if you try `table.appendTableRow().appendTableCell("test");`? What are the contents of a tableRow added by the UI, vs one added by your code?

Comment: aaaaand it works! :) Thank You! So, in order to identify all the "ghost table rows" (to remove them) do you think that checking for  `tableRow.getNumCells() === 0` will do? 
Can I accept a comment? Do you wanna add an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Answer added - when I am only guessing, I use comments. I believe that checking for 0 cells will be a sufficient test for identifying rows to remove. The alternative, getting as test, would pick "blank" as well as "empty" rows, so not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `table.appendTableRow()`, you are appending empty rows - and *empty* isn't the same as *blank*.

In contrast, the UI is adding blank rows, which have child [`tableCell`s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell). Any visible content in a row ends up contained in a tableCell; so by adding at least one of those to your row, you should end up with a visible row.

Try `table.appendTableRow().appendTableCell();` instead.